# Android Studio Kotlin: RecyclerView must not be Null RuntimeException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have been trying to resolve an issue being thrown at runtime where the recyclerview I am using is null. From most examples of this error message I have seen online it is usually when using a RecyclerView is being used in a fragment. This RecyclerView is just being used in a normal Kotlin Activity.

**Error When OrderActivity.kt is opened**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pos, PID: 6004
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pos/com.example.pos.OrderActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: orderRecyclerView must not be null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: orderRecyclerView must not be null
        at com.example.pos.OrderActivity.onCreate(OrderActivity.kt:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**OrderActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.pos

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.multiplerecyclerview.OrderAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_order.*

class OrderActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        // Adapter class is initialized and list is passed in the param.
        val orderAdapter = OrderAdapter(this, getItemsList())

        //Set the LayoutManager that this RecyclerView will use.
        orderRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        //adapter instance is set to the recyclerview to inflate the items.
        orderRecyclerView.adapter = orderAdapter
    }

    private fun getItemsList(): ArrayList<DataModel> {
        val list = ArrayList<DataModel>()

        list.add(DataModel("Romana","1","12.50", "Pepperoni", "Aubergine", "Ex Mozz.", "Salami", OrderAdapter.TOPPINGS_4))
        list.add(DataModel("American","1","12.50", viewType = OrderAdapter.NO_TOPPING))

        return list
    }
}
```

**OrderAdapter.kt**

```
package com.example.multiplerecyclerview

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.pos.DataModel
import com.example.pos.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.food_item.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.food_item_4.view.*


class OrderAdapter(val context: Context, val items: ArrayList<DataModel>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    companion object {
        const val NO_TOPPING = 1
        const val TOPPINGS_4 = 4
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        if(viewType == NO_TOPPING) {
            return ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.food_item,
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )
        } else if (viewType == TOPPINGS_4) {
            return ViewHolder4(
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.food_item_4,
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )
        } else {
            return ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.food_item,
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items.get(position)

        if(holder is ViewHolder) {

            holder.productQuantity.text = item.itemName
            holder.productName.text = item.itemName
            holder.productPrice.text = item.itemPrice

        } else if(holder is ViewHolder4) {

            holder.productQuantity4.text = item.itemName
            holder.productName4.text = item.itemName
            holder.productPrice4.text = item.itemPrice

            holder.topping1.text = item.topping1
            holder.topping2.text = item.topping2
            holder.topping3.text = item.topping3
            holder.topping4.text = item.topping4
        }

    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return items[position].viewType
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val productQuantity = view.productQuantityView
        val productName = view.productNameView
        val productPrice = view.productPriceView
    }

    class ViewHolder4(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val productQuantity4 = view.productQuantityView4
        val productName4 = view.productNameView4
        val productPrice4 = view.productPriceView4

        val topping1 = view.topping1View
        val topping2 = view.topping2View
        val topping3 = view.topping3View
        val topping4 = view.topping4View
    }
}
```

**DataModel.kt**

```
package com.example.pos

data class DataModel(val itemName: String, val itemQuantity: String, val itemPrice: String, val topping1: String? = null,  val topping2: String? = null,  val topping3: String? = null,  val topping4: String? = null, val viewType: Int)
```

**activity_order.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OrderActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/customerButton"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="65dp"
        android:text="Customer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cancelOrderButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/sideOrderSwitch"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
        android:text="Side Orders"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dealOneButton"
        android:layout_width="132dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:text="Deal One"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/sideOrderSwitch"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dealTwoButton"
        android:layout_width="132dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:text="Deal Two"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dealOneButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dealThreeButton"
        android:layout_width="132dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:text="Deal Three"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dealTwoButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dealMaxButton"
        android:layout_width="132dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="Deal Max"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dealThreeButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelOrderButton"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="Cancel Order"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/margButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Margherita"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sideOrderSwitch" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/americanButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="American"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/margButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dealOneButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/HawaiianButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Hawaiian"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/americanButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dealTwoButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/romanaButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Romana"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/HawaiianButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dealThreeButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cheese4Button"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="4 Cheeses"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/romanaButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dealMaxButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/polloButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Pollo"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/margButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/melanzanaButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Melanzana"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/polloButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/americanButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/vegButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Veg Pizza"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/melanzanaButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/HawaiianButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/queryButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Query"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vegButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/romanaButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/whiteRockButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="White Rock"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/queryButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cheese4Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sorrentoButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Sorrento"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/polloButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dylanParkButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Dylan's Park"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/sorrentoButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/melanzanaButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/coliemoreButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Coliemore Harbour"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dylanParkButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vegButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bullockButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Bullock Harbour"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/coliemoreButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/queryButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fortyFootButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="40 Foot"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bullockButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/whiteRockButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/catsButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Cat's Ladder"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sorrentoButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/killineyHillButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Killiney Hill"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/catsButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dylanParkButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/killineyBeachButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Killiney Beach"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/killineyHillButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/coliemoreButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/castleButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="The Castle"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/killineyBeachButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bullockButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/martelloButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Martello Tower"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/castleButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fortyFootButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loretoButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Loreto"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/catsButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/vicoButton"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Vico"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/loretoButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/killineyHillButton" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/orderRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="633dp"
        android:layout_height="575dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fortyFootButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cancelOrderButton"
        tools:listitem="@layout/food_item" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <!--android:onClick="insertItem" -->
```

**food_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewItem1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="12dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productQuantityView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/shopColour"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productNameView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/productQuantityView"
            android:text="12'' Killiney Beach"
            android:textColor="@color/shopColour"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productPriceView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/productNameView"
            android:text="14.50"
            android:textColor="@color/shopColour"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**food_item4.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewItem4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="12dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productQuantityView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/shopColour"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productNameView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/productQuantityView4"
            android:text="12'' Killiney Beach"
            android:textColor="@color/shopColour"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productPriceView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/productNameView4"
            android:text="14.50"
            android:textColor="@color/shopColour"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topping1View"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/productPriceView4"
            android:text="Pepperoni"
            android:textColor="@color/logoYellow"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topping2View"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/topping1View"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/productPriceView4"
            android:text="Aubergine"
            android:textColor="@color/logoYellow"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topping3View"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/topping1View"
            android:text="Semi Dried Tomatos"
            android:textColor="@color/logoYellow"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topping4View"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/topping1View"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/topping2View"
            android:text="Smoked Applewood"
            android:textColor="@color/logoYellow"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

this is the layout you're using in the create of your activity

but you've posted

> activity_order.xml

and this is the file which contains the specific component you're referencing (the recyclerview)

so you need to change your setContentView in your activity to:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_order)
```

---

synthetic imports will (quite happily) add imports to resolve references, but those references could be to entirely different and irrelevant files.

you can see here:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_order.*
```

it is importing everything from this file, but that's not the file you've used inside your setContentView, so that's why it crashes

Comment: [The deprecation is also worth mentioning](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are using wrong layout in OrderActivity. Take a look at this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

It should be:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_order)
```